# gulpfile only running once with watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have this as my gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task( 'default', ['sass'] );

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/theme.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

I works and compiles the sass however it stops running instead of watching? I am not too familiar with how gulp works so help would really be appreciated!

the output in console looks like this:

```
[13:14:29] Using gulpfile ~/public_html/mysite/gulpfile.js                                                                                                               
[13:14:29] Starting 'sass'...                                                                                                                                                               
[13:14:31] Finished 'sass' after 1.2 s                                                                                                                                                      
[13:14:31] Starting 'default'...                                                                                                                                                            
[13:14:31] Finished 'default' after 15 μs
```

Comment: You need to include the `sass:watch` task in your `default` task. Including *tasks* to the **default task** tells the gulp to execute the series of tasks in chronological order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't started `sass:watch` task.

```
gulp.task( 'default', ['sass', 'sass:watch'] );
```